# Multiple File Upload with Dropzone.js and Laravel MediaLibrary Package

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropzone.js

i have implemented Dropzone.js to upload multiple files with my form, it works fine but i want to change the accepted file types attribute, it is only accepting documents i would like to upload audio files.. Is this possible?

i followed this step by step to get it working; https://laraveldaily.com/multiple-file-upload-with-dropzone-js-and-laravel-medialibrary-package/

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="document">Documents</label>
        <div class="needsclick dropzone" id="document-dropzone">
        </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var uploadedDocumentMap = {}
  Dropzone.options.documentDropzone = {
    url: '{{ route('music.storeMedia') }}',
    maxFilesize: 10, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    success: function (file, response) {
      $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="document[]" value="' + response.name + '">')
      uploadedDocumentMap[file.name] = response.name
    },
    removedfile: function (file) {
      file.previewElement.remove()
      var name = ''
      if (typeof file.file_name !== 'undefined') {
        name = file.file_name
      } else {
        name = uploadedDocumentMap[file.name]
      }
      $('form').find('input[name="document[]"][value="' + name + '"]').remove()
    }
    ,
    init: function () {
      @if(isset($project) && $project->document)
        var files =
          {!! json_encode($project->document) !!}
        for (var i in files) {
          var file = files[i]
          this.options.addedfile.call(this, file)
          file.previewElement.classList.add('dz-complete')
          $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="document[]" value="' + file.file_name + '">')
        }
      @endif
    }


  }
</script>
```

Any help will be truly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reading dropzone.js plugin documentation, yes, you can with the option **[acceptedFiles](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles)**.

By default it is set to `null` thus allowing for any file type upload.

You can set your own desired file types by specifying a list of file extension or file [MIME Type](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/).

In the code below I specified to allow only `JPG`, `GIF` or `MP3` like so : `acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .gif, .mp3'`, I've removed your PHP code in the javascript for demo purposes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>


<fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="document">Documents</label>
        <div class="needsclick dropzone" id="document-dropzone">
        </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var uploadedDocumentMap = {};
  Dropzone.options.documentDropzone = {
    url: '/echo/html/',
    maxFilesize: 10, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    success: function (file, response) {
      $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="document[]" value="' + response.name + '">')
      uploadedDocumentMap[file.name] = response.name
    },
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .gif, .mp3', //file extension or MIME Type to accept uploading
    removedfile: function (file) {
      file.previewElement.remove()
      var name = ''
      if (typeof file.file_name !== 'undefined') {
        name = file.file_name
      } else {
        name = uploadedDocumentMap[file.name]
      }
      $('form').find('input[name="document[]"][value="' + name + '"]').remove()
    }
    ,
    init: function (e) {
        //dropbox initialization done!
        
    }


  }
</script>
```

That being said, you should always check the file extension on the server side aswell before uploading because you can never trust what's coming from a client browser request.

Also, I would recommend to only check file [MIME Type](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/) as anyone can change a file extension by renaming it so in our case this would change to `acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg, image/gif, audio/mpeg'`.

If you want to allow only audio files, put your desired file extensions or the [MIME Type](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/).